# Match multiple lines on a pattern and return placeholders

Tags: python, regex

I find it hard to summarize my question, so I'll start with an example. I have a textarea and each line in it must validate the following pattern:

```
{new_field} is {func} of {field}[,{field}]
```

Where `is` and `of` are fixed terms, `{new_field}` and `{field}` are variable terms and need to be returned somehow and things between `[` and `]` are optional. I need that to return a list of dicts, each one containing the variable terms extracted from each line in the textarea.

So, for example, if I have the following input:

```
name is concat of first_name, last_name
price is sum of product, taxes, shipping
```

I would need an output of:

```
[{'new_field': 'name', 'func': 'concat', 'fields': ['first_name', 'last_name']},
 {'new_field': 'price', 'func': 'sum', 'fields': ['product', 'taxes', 'shipping']}]
```

Now, I thought of `split`ting the whole line and use indexes to match the terms but if I need to customize how the placeholders look like, I will have a hard time doing this. Then, I thought of using regex, but sadly I have no idea how to start/what to use from the `re` module. Any help and hints would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
s = """name is concat of first_name, last_name
price is sum of product, taxes, shipping"""

out = []

for line in s.splitlines():
    new_field,func,fields = re.match(r'(\w+) is (\w+) of (.*)',line).groups()
    out.append({'new_field':new_field,
                'func':func,
                'fields':fields.split(',')})
```

output:

```
out
Out[20]: 
[{'fields': ['first_name', ' last_name'],
  'func': 'concat',
  'new_field': 'name'},
 {'fields': ['product', ' taxes', ' shipping'],
  'func': 'sum',
  'new_field': 'price'}]
```

Note that I'm pretty terse with the above, which is nice for demonstration code but isn't great if you expect robustness.  At the minimum you would want to check if `match is not None` and likely do some more sophisticated parsing on `fields` to make sure that it matches the grammar that you've specified.  *a la*

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    match = re.match(r'(\w+) is (\w+) of (.*)',line)
    if match:
        new_field,func,fields = match.groups()
        out.append({'new_field': new_field,
                    'func': func,
                    'fields': some_processing_func(fields)})
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach would be:

```
import re

text = ['name is concat of first_name, last_name',
'price is sum of product, taxes, shipping']

pattern = "(\w+)\s+is\s+(\w+)\s+of\s+(\w+)\s?(.*)"

res = []
for line in text:
    m = re.match(pattern,line)      
    res.append({
         'new_field': m.group(1),
         'func': m.group(2),
         'fields': [x.strip() for x in m.groups()[-1].split(',') if x]
         })
print res
```